# How can I include function from string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to do something like:

```
.Helper.ps1
```

But I have no helper file. I have code as string.

I would expect something like this:

```
.$helper
```

or

```
 & $helper
```

Where value of `$helper` variable is: `function Test($test) { $test }`
But both doesn't work, any ideas?
As a workaround I'm saving variable to temp file and load it from there, but it doesn't look too smart.

Thanks
Andrey

Comment: "But both doesn't work" means what? Error? Unexpected behaviour? Bluescreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$helper = 'function XTest($test) { $test }'
Invoke-Expression $helper
xtest 2
```